# How to delete a column and get html without affecting the dom in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net application. I would like to pass the grid view HTML without the delete button at the end to generate pdf using jquery without affecting the DOM. So I need to get the html of the gridview without last th and td. How will I be able to do that?

```
<div id="container>
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass = "Grid" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Item" HeaderText="Item" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
</div>

<Button class="Print-Button" ID="btnExportPdf" data-val="PRT">Export to PDF</Button>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).on("click", ".Print-Button", function (e) {
                var ItemHTML = $('#container').html();

// I have to remove the delete button (last column) and send to code behind to generate pdf
                var dataVal = { value: ItemHTML };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "webApplication1.aspx/GetURL",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataVal),
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: added more information. Request to reopen.

Comment: maybe you can split the html by <tr> , <td> and then find you last column index and just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like below**

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Item" HeaderText="Item" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="hideonprint" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<button type="button" class="btn">Export to PDF</button>

<div id="box"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('.btn').click(function (e) {
            jQuery('.hideonprint').hide();
            var gv = jQuery('#GridView1').html();
            jQuery('.hideonprint').show();
            jQuery('#box').html(gv);
        });
    });

</script>
```